# Dynamics CRM--> Azure Blob Storage--> 40 MB file upload gives Timeout Error. Custom Plugin on PostCreate of annotation

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, dynamics-crm-online

In Dynamics CRM Online, We have Custom Solution build which stores Large file as block-blobs on Azure Blob Storage.
When I try to upload File of 40 MB I get Timeout Error. Error Log below.

What I have read is that

> Uploading a block blob that is no more than 256 MB (64 MB for
>   requests using REST versions before 2016-05-31) can be a single write
>   operation using Put Blob. However, uploading a larger blob requires
>   some more effort. Break it down in blocks of max 4 or 100MB depending
>   on the REST API version that you use.

Edit: I did some more brainstorming with some Trail and Error. What I found out is that from CRM using (c#) Plugin I could easily send File upto 80 MB and this is good amount. Anyhow CRM has restriction of file size upto 128MB.

With regard to my particular problem, i also found out that main issue is caused by HTML Page, which is used as Drag and Drop for adding File to CRM and then in turn to Azure Blob.

Summary: RESTAPI for Azure is not the problem, it more lies on Dynamics CRM Side. We have to respect Timeout with efficient way to extracting Bytes from File and uploading it to Azure.

As mentioned above 256 MB file should not break it down but still I get Timeout.
Here is the method I believe is causing the Issue.

```
public HttpWebRequest CreateRESTRequest(string method, string resource, byte[] requestBody, SortedList<string, string> headers = null,
            string ifMatch = "", string md5 = "")
        {
          DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
          string uri = Endpoint + resource;

          HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
          request.Method = method;
          request.ContentLength = 0;
          request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", now.ToString("R", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
          request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2017-04-17");

          if (IsTableStorage)
          {
            request.ContentType = "application/atom+xml";

            request.Headers.Add("DataServiceVersion", "1.0;NetFx");
            request.Headers.Add("MaxDataServiceVersion", "1.0;NetFx");
          }

          if (headers != null)
          {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> header in headers)
            {
              // This control requires that we set the ContentType through its property.
              if (header.Key.Equals("Content-Type", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
              {
                request.ContentType = header.Value;
              }
              else
              {
                request.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
              }
            }
          }

          if (requestBody?.Length > 0)
          {
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
            request.ContentLength = requestBody.Length;
          }

          request.Headers.Add("Authorization", AuthorizationHeader(method, now, request, ifMatch, md5));

          if (requestBody?.Length > 0)
          {
            request.GetRequestStream().Write(requestBody, 0, requestBody.Length);
            request.GetRequestStream().Close();
          }

          return request;
        }
```

`Uploading Test File.pptx failed Reason: "The plug-in execution failed because no Sandbox Hosts are currently available. Please check that you have a Sandbox server configured and that it is running.\r\nSystem.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:03:30'. ---> System.IO.IOException: The write operation failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:03:30'. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine\r\n at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)\r\n at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnection.WriteNow(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, BufferManager bufferManager)\r\n at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)\r\n at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.StartWriting(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)\r\n at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n\r\nServer stack trace: \r\n at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout, BufferManager bufferManager)\r\n at System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnSendCore(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.OnSend(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n at System.ServiceModel.Channels.OutputChannel.Send(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)\r\n at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)\r\n\r\nException rethrown at [0]: \r\n at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)\r\n at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)\r\n at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.ISandboxHost.ExecuteAndReturnTraceInfo(SandboxCallInfo callInfo, SandboxPluginExecutionContext requestContext, Guid pluginAssemblyId, Int32 sourceHash, String assemblyName, Guid pluginTypeId, String pluginTypeName, String pluginConfiguration, String pluginSecureConfig, String assemblyContents, Boolean returnTraceInfo)\r\n at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxPlugin.Execute(SandboxClient client, SandboxCallTracker callTracker, IExecutionContext requestContext, String assemblyContents, Boolean returnTraceInfo)\r\n at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxCodeUnit.ExecuteInternal(SandboxClient client, IExecutionContext context, SandboxTraceContext sandboxTraceContext, SandboxCallTracker callTracker, Guid parentExecutionId, String assemblyContents, Boolean& isSafeToRetry, Boolean& executeDone)\r\n at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxCodeUnit.<>c__DisplayClass24_0.<Execute>b__0(): Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #D2641555"`

Comment: It does not make sens that a 40MB file take a while to upload... Have you tried using the .NET blob storage SDK or using Microsoft or Logic app ? Flow and Logic App have built-in connectors to D365 and Blob storage

Comment: Using :NET blob storage SDK is seamless and easy way, as the methods from SDK does most of the work of creating chunks and uploading and combining.
But I am using Plugin (c#) code from Dynamics CRM and if i use External dll I need to Merge them and then I loose the functionality of Debugging, hence RESTAPI is the way.

Comment: My D365 colleagues uses to offload this kind of work to azure functions.

Comment: @Thomas absolutely agreed. This is a perfect use-case for Azure Functions!

Answer (score 0):

The maximum time that a plug-in may run in Dynamics 365 is 3 minutes. If your plug-in might take longer than that, it is recommended that your plug-in trigger a queue or reach out to some external service that will run the code without a timeout.

1. Your plug-in fires and passes a record id to an external service or queue.
2. Your external code fires and reads the record from Dynamics and uploads the file to Azure.

This way the plug-in will execute quickly.

Comment: I have edited my question Description.
It is more of a efficient way of extracting Bytes from Document.

Comment: This will be the most efficient method. I know it is convenient to put this code inside the plugin itself, but the problem is that long-running code of any kind should not be put in async plugins or custom workflow activities. If the code takes more than a few seconds to execute, you run the risk of backing up system jobs in the async service. Even though the async service is multi-threaded, if all the threads are running long tasks, then your other workflows have to wait. Don't make the async service work hard - have it offload the hard work to external processes.